# Combining and loading Json content as python dictionary

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-2.7, dataframe, dictionary

Ihave 100 json files  (file1- file 100)in my directory.All these 100 have the same fields and  my aim is to load  allcontents in one dictionary or dataframe.Basically  the content of each file (ie file1- file100) willbe a row for my dictionary or dataframe

To test the code first,I wrote a script to load contents from  one json file

```
file2 = open(r"\Users\sbz\file1.txt","w+")
import json
import traceback

def read_json_file(file2):
    with open(file2, "r") as f:
        try:
            return json.load(f)
```

for combining i wrote this

```
def combine_dictionaries(dictionary_list):
    my_dictionary = {}
    for key in dictionary_list:
        my_dictionary.update(key)
    return my_dictionary
```

I am  unable to load the file or display contents of dictionary using print(file2)
Is there something I  am missing? Or is there better wayto loop in all 100 files and load them as a single dictionary?

Comment: Please describe (1) how you call these functions, and (2) what precisely does not work, and how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `json.load` isn't working, my guess is that your JSON file is probably formatted incorrectly.  Try getting it to work with a simple file like:

```
{
  "test": 0
}
```

After that works, then try loading one of your 100 files.  I copy-pasted your `read_json_file` function and I'm able to see the data in my file: `print(read_json_file("data.json"))`

For looping through the files and combining them:
It doesn't look like your `combine_dictionaries` function is 100% there yet for what you want to do.  `update` doesn't merge the dictionaries into rows as you want; it will replace the keys of one dictionary with the keys of another, and since each file has the same fields the resulting dictionary will be the last one in the list.  Technically, a list of dictionaries is already a list of rows which is what you want and you can index the list based on row number, for example, `list_of_dictionaries[0]` will get the dictionary created from file1 if you fill the list in order of file1 to file100.  If you want to go further than file numbers, you can put all of these dictionaries into another dictionary if you can generate a unique key for each dictionary:

```
def combine_dictionaries(dictionary_list):
    my_dictionary = {}
    for dictionary in dictionary_list:
        my_dictionary[generate_key(dictionary)] = dictionary
    return my_dictionary
```

Where `generate_key` is a function that will return a key unique to that dictionary.  Now `combined_dictionary.get(0)` will get file1's dictionary, and `combined_dictionary.get(0).get("somefield")` will get the "somefield" data from file1.

Comment: i realized it wasproblem with file format as i tested with asmaller json file quick clarification : if iwant to save this printed dictionary as a dataframe  or save it as dictionary variable ,how do i do it for print(read_json_file("data.json")).

Comment: I haven't really worked with dataframes for a while, so I'm unsure with that way, but with normal dictionaries I'm pretty sure you can use the json module to convert the dictionary to a json string with json.dumps(some_dictionary) and then you can write the string to a file.